# Python get normal HEX format for MAC-Adress

Tags: python, macos, format, hex, mac-address

I want a normal format for the MAC-Address I got from get_node().

The format I get is 0x0L0xdL0x60L0x76L0x31L0xd6L, I want the 0x deleted and the L-term to a real hex number. It should be  00-0D-60-76-31-D6 .

How can I realize this?

```
def getNetworkData (self):
    myHostname, myIP, myMAC =  AU.getHostname()

    touple1 = (myMAC & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40
    touple2 = (myMAC & 0x00FF00000000) >> 32
    touple3 = (myMAC & 0x0000FF000000) >> 24
    touple4 = (myMAC & 0x000000FF0000) >> 16
    touple5 = (myMAC & 0x00000000FF00) >> 8
    touple6 = (myMAC & 0x0000000000FF) >> 0

    readableMACadress = hex(touple1) + hex(touple2) + hex(touple3) + hex(touple4) + hex(touple5) + hex(touple6) 

    print readableMACadress

    return myHostname, myIP, readableMACadress
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
readableMACaddress = '%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X' % (touple1, touple2, touple3, touple4, touple5, touple6)
```

More concisely, you can eliminate the temporary `touple` variables by using

```
readableMACaddress = '-'.join('%02X' % ((myMAC >> 8*i) & 0xff) for i in reversed(xrange(6)))
```

Comment: `%X` formats a number as uppercase hexadecimal, without `0x` or `L`. The `02` means "pad with leading zeroes to 2 places". So each `%02X` formats a number in two-digit uppercase hex.

Comment: The concise replacement uses `'-'.join` to join together six hex bytes, which are calculated using `(myMAC >> 8*i) & 0xff`. We iterate `i` from 5 to 0 using `reversed(xrange(6))`.

Comment: I'd have used `xrange(5,-1,-1)` perhaps. Still, +1 for a great solution.

Comment: I find using `reversed` to be a more readable way to express reverse iteration. Matter of preference :)