# Get MAC address in python and append to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I get my mac address in python in the form of: \x##\x##\x##\x##\x##\x##?
I'm trying to construct an ethernet header and generate the source hardware address automatically.

I'm using `uuid.getnode()` to get the mac address as a 48 bit integer. How can I convert it so I can append it to a string already in that format?
ie: `eth_header = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff" + magicconvert(uuid.getnode())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are many ways, how about this one:

```
import uuid
hdr="\xff"*6
mac=uuid.getnode()
txt="%012X"%mac
as_b=[int("".join(x),16) for x in map(None,*(txt[::2],txt[1::2]))]
as_s="".join(chr(b) for b in as_b)
out=hdr+as_s
```

Answer (score 3):

The user [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404622/python-get-normal-hex-format-for-mac-adress) answered this on September 13th.  Credit goes to him:

```
    '-'.join('%02X' % ((uuid.getnode() >> 8*i) & 0xff) for i in reversed(xrange(6)))
```

Edit this to give you the string in formatted how you'd like.

I'd also like to take this moment to say that "uuid.getnode()" may very well be returning a random value, or it may be getting the MAC address of any random network interface on your system.  From what I can tell, there really is no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip
import uuid

token = "\\x"
mac_address = "%012x" % uuid.getnode()
iter_mac_address = iter(mac_address)
"%s%s" % (token, token.join(a+b for a, b in izip(iter_mac_address, iter_mac_address)))
```